# Not able to login for posting image on my Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

I am using following code to post image on Facebook wall. 
it's working fine.

Problem is  --> if the device having Facebook Application i am not able to post image on wall.

-->The device does't having Facebook App. it's working without any problems.

please help me where is the problem. 
this is the code i am using here.

```
public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity  {

private static final String APP_ID = "269876589726953";
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

      private Facebook facebook;
      private String messageToPost; 
      private Bitmap mBitmap;

      public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
           Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                  editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
                  editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    return editor.commit();
            }

    public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    mBitmap = CropImage.getBitmapCrop();    

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    restoreCredentials(facebook);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.share);

    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    if (facebookMessage == null){
        facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
    }
    messageToPost = facebookMessage;
}

public void doNotShare(View button){
    finish();
}
public void share(View button){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}

public void loginAndPostToWall(){
     facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
}

public void postToWall(String message)  { 


    // posting image on FB wall
    byte[] data = null;

    Bitmap bi = mBitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());        
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);

    finish();   
}

public class PhotoUploadListener extends com.facebook.android.BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {         
        //dialog.dismiss();
        //showToast("Image shared on your facebook wall!");          
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
       //dialog.dismiss();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null){
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
}

private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small Changes in the code (facebook package)

Look into authorize function in **facebook.java** file. try to comment out the **singlesignon** and use `startdialog()` only.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have used null here. As far as I know, instead of this,

```
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

it should be something like this,

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

And still if your problem exists because of an existing Facebook app in the device, then you might have make the login compulsory.

In this piece of your code,

```
public void loginAndPostToWall(){
     facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

do this change,

```
public void loginAndPostToWall(){
     facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

It should do the trick.